# Android - button text color not overrided

Tags: java, android

My theme is:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="actionBarTheme">@style/MyActionBarTheme</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarStyle</item>
    <item name="circularProgressBarStyle">@style/CircularProgressBar</item>
    <item name="actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabText</item>
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="actionBarTabBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarTab</item>
</style>
```

I don't see any style here that can affect my button text color because they are for action bar styling. But I still cannot change my button text color in layout file:

```
<Button
    ...
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:textColor="@color/yellow"
    ... />
```

I can change `textSize` here but not the `textColor`. Anyone can tell me why? Shouldn't it be the highest priority for styling? (That means overriding style.xml config if there is one). Please correct me if I am wrong. Much appreciation!

Comment: you can apply custom style make copy of style and modify it and  apply to button.

Comment: can you show `@color/yellow`

Comment: @PhanVănLinh nope, but I figured out to make it work by applying `selector` in `color.xml`, stating both enable and disable have the same color...though it is a stupid solution

Answer (score 0):

This is what you should be doing:

```
android:textColor="@android:color/yellow"
```

instead of

```
android:textColor="@color/yellow"
```

Comment: But that is Android framework's color, I want to use my own one

Answer (score 0):

button.setTextColor(getApplication().getResources().getColor(R.color.green));

button.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ff1100"));

Comment: That will work, but actually I want to keep UI config in resources instead of puting it in logic code

Comment: try out this...<Button android:id="@+id/mybtn" 
        android:text="text textx "  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:textStyle="bold" 
        android:textColor="#ff0000" />

Answer (score 0):

add this into your style

```
 <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/colorPrimary</item>
```

or

you can add property android:background to button class like this

```
<Button
...
android:textSize="22sp"
android:background="@color/yellow"
... />
```

Answer (score 0):

As TejjD said :

> This is what you should be doing:
>
> android:textColor="@android:color/yellow" instead of
>
> android:textColor="@color/yellow"

You have to define your custom color in Colors.xml file.